# Multiples computations in one iteration with Spark

Tags: apache-spark

How can I iterate over a big collection of files producing different results in just one step with Spark? For example:

```
val tweets : RDD[Tweet] = ...
val topWords : RDD[String] = getTopWords(tweets)
val topHashtags : RDD[String] = getTopHashtags(tweets)

topWords.collect().foreach(println)
topHashtags.collect().foreach(println)
```

It looks like Spark is going to iterate twice over the tweets dataset. Is there any way to prevent this? Is Spark smart enough to make this kind of optimizations?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark will keep data loaded into CPU cache as long as it can, but that's not something you should rely on, so your best bet is to `tweets.cache` so that after the initial load then it will be working off of a memory store. The only other solution you would have is to combine your two functions and return a tuple of `(resultType1, resultType2)`